# How to reduce clutter in html5 and bootstrap (or: howto create html5 components)?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, web-component

I have an HTML5 bootstrap web page with two layers of tabs within tabs. 
Each main tab has its own set of tabs and each tab is basically a different page. 
How can I develop the HTML of each tab as its own file and then include it in the main page?

Also, can I "reuse" such an element with only minor changes (Say the title of the tab and the field names shown)?

I'm looking for something quick and easy. I read about Google Web-Components but am under the impression that its not for every browser yet, and only something evolving now.

Here's sample code that under menu 1 has sub menus...  I want to have small terse html files each with a few lines of code.

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

            <div id="divmaintabs">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
              <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
              <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
              <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <h3>Main tabs</h3>
                <div id="homecontent"><p>A div with much content.</p></div>
              </div>
              <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Menu 1</h3>
                <!--- sub Tabs under menu 1 --->
                  <div id="divtabsundermenu1">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu20">Menu20</a></li>
              <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu21">Menu 21</a></li>
              <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu22">Menu 22</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
              <div id="menu20" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <h3>menu20</h3>
                <p>menu 20 content</p>
              </div>
              <div id="menu21" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Menu 21</h3>
                <p>Some content in menu 21.    </p>
              </div>
              <div id="menu22" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Menu 22</h3>
                <p>Some content in menu 22.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
                <!----  end of internal tabs -->
              </div>
              <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Menu 2</h3>
                <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

I don't know why the code is not working, but you can understand the idea. I made code with another tab page under the first one.

Each of the tabs will have a whole "page-full" of code, and it can quickly get out of hand.

So under menu 1 (this is all in Bootstrap) I put the subtabs dev written in a different html file?
And working with cshtml (nancyfx views) can I do the same and it will work, 
or do all the divs and stuff need to be served in advance (together? how does that work?)

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery.load()

```
$('#MyContainer').load('some/path/MyHtml.html');
```

And to switch names

```
$('#MyNameElement').text('MyNewName');
```

=)

Comment: So wait...  I'm editing the question and asking that you edit the answer with sample code for that